# Overlay component changes component size when overlay is off

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have an app.vue dashboard which consists of multiple components. The component changes its size to max width when the overlay is turned off upon button click and if the overlay is on it shrinks back. I want the size to be full width/fixed to max does not matter if on or off.

I am using vue3, vuetify3 components. Here is the live example.

http://v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/dashboard

The component name is recent swaps. The overlay button is Swap History.

[Here is my code if you want to have a look](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)